# JSF phase Render Response not getting called

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el

In process of migrating an app from WAS7 to Tomcat7.

I can deploy and start the webapp. The problem I am facing is that JSF lifecyle(s) dont seem to complete when executing actions. (Not sure if that is what is happening, refer to explanation scenario below)

To monitor life cycle I wrote a simple lifecycle code and configured in `faces-config.xml`

`LifeCycleListener.java`

```
package com.csc.phaseEvent;

import javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseId;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseListener;

public class LifeCycleListener implements PhaseListener {

    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        return PhaseId.ANY_PHASE;
    }

    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        System.out.println("START PHASE " + event.getPhaseId());
    }

    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        System.out.println("END PHASE " + event.getPhaseId());
    }

}
```

So this gives me output on console `StartPhase` and `End Phase` for each phase, but Nothing happens after `END PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION 5` refer to log

```
START PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
END PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
START PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
END PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
START PHASE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
END PHASE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
START PHASE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
END PHASE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
START PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-1] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 16:38:29.984: ServiceDelegator : DEBUG : :Current Process Stack [[openSession.SelectRoleSuccess, coordinatorDesktop.CoordinatorDesktop, openSession.SelectRole]]
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-1] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 16:38:29.985: ServiceDelegator : DEBUG : :Executing Invoke activity [SelectRole]
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-1] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 16:38:29.986: ServiceDelegator : DEBUG : :invoking service action class [SET_ROLE]
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-1] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 16:38:29.992: BaseServiceAction : DEBUG : :SetRole - Session Key used BAC4DB1C-ADDA-4009-4000-96BD19DEA88F/mukul
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-1] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 16:38:29.993: java.lang.Class : DEBUG : :Executing findUserSession().
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-1] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 16:38:29.994: java.lang.Class : DEBUG : mukul:Executing persistActiveRoles(UserSession inputUserSession).
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-1] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 16:38:30.02: ServiceDelegator : DEBUG : mukul:Current Process Stack [[openSession.SelectRoleSuccess, coordinatorDesktop.CoordinatorDesktop, openSession.SelectRoleSuccess]]
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-1] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 16:38:30.03: ServiceDelegator : DEBUG : mukul:Executing Invoke activity [SelectRoleSuccess]
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-1] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 16:38:30.04: ServiceDelegator : DEBUG : mukul:invoking embedded process [coordinatorDesktop]
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-1] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 16:38:30.05: ServiceDelegator : DEBUG : mukul:Current Process Stack [[openSession.SelectRoleSuccess, coordinatorDesktop.CoordinatorDesktop, openSession.SelectRoleSuccess, coordinatorDesktop.CoordinatorDesktop]]
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-1] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logXML:260)  - 2013/02/15 16:38:30.06: ServiceDelegator : XML : mukul:process event final result [<process-step-result><outcome>coordinatorDesktop</outcome><result-params><has-errors><![CDATA[false]]></has-errors><error></error><PROCESS_STACK><![CDATA[openSession.SelectRoleSuccess$$coordinatorDesktop.CoordinatorDesktop$$openSession.SelectRoleSuccess$$coordinatorDesktop.CoordinatorDesktop$$]]></PROCESS_STACK><PersistElements><roleID><![CDATA[FullRep]]></roleID></PersistElements><Session><![CDATA[USK:BAC4DB1CADDA4009400096BD19DEA88F/
]]></Session><SelectRoleActionResult><![CDATA[success]]></SelectRoleActionResult><successInd><![CDATA[success]]></successInd><outcome><![CDATA[success]]></outcome></result-params></process-step-result>]
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-1] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 16:38:30.07: XMLUtils : DEBUG : mukul:node = error  NOT in XML <process-step-result><outcome>coordinatorDesktop</outcome><result-params><has-errors><![CDATA[false]]></has-errors><error></error><PROCESS_STACK><![CDATA[openSession.SelectRoleSuccess$$coordinatorDesktop.CoordinatorDesktop$$openSession.SelectRoleSuccess$$coordinatorDesktop.CoordinatorDesktop$$]]></PROCESS_STACK><PersistElements><roleID><![CDATA[FullRep]]></roleID></PersistElements><Session><![CDATA[USK:BAC4DB1CADDA4009400096BD19DEA88F/
]]></Session><SelectRoleActionResult><![CDATA[success]]></SelectRoleActionResult><successInd><![CDATA[success]]></successInd><outcome><![CDATA[success]]></outcome></result-params></process-step-result>
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-1] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 16:38:30.15: pagecode.authorization.Roles : DEBUG : mukul:Persisted element [User] value [mukul]
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-1] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 16:38:30.16: pagecode.authorization.Roles : DEBUG : mukul:Persisted element [systems] value [[CLIENT-DB, XMLG, CyberLifeWS, Hibernate, CyberLifeWS_VSAM, AWDnative]]
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-1] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 16:38:30.17: pagecode.authorization.Roles : DEBUG : mukul:Persisted element [ServletURL] value [http://localhost:8080/csa/servlet/Initializer]
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-1] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 16:38:30.17: pagecode.authorization.Roles : DEBUG : mukul:Persisted element [currSelectionspagecode.authorization.AdminLogon] value [{}]
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-1] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 16:38:30.18: pagecode.authorization.Roles : DEBUG : mukul:Persisted element [currSelectionspagecode.authorization.Roles] value [{rowTable= FullRep}]
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-1] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 16:38:30.19: pagecode.authorization.Roles : DEBUG : mukul:Persisted element [PROCESS_STACK] value [openSession.SelectRoleSuccess$$coordinatorDesktop.CoordinatorDesktop$$openSession.SelectRoleSuccess$$coordinatorDesktop.CoordinatorDesktop$$]
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-1] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 16:38:30.20: pagecode.authorization.Roles : DEBUG : mukul:Persisted element [Session] value [USK%3ABAC4DB1CADDA4009400096BD19DEA88F%2F%0C%14%0A%14%0B]
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-1] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 16:38:30.20: pagecode.authorization.Roles : DEBUG : mukul:Persisted element [prevSelectionspagecode.authorization.AdminLogon] value [{}]
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-1] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 16:38:30.21: pagecode.authorization.Roles : DEBUG : mukul:Persisted element [roles] value [[Manager, FullRep, PolAdminRep, loaderRunner, Agent, CustomerService.Level1Analyst, PolOwnerService.Level1Analyst, Approver, AgentFull, OfflineUser, PolOwnerService.ReadOnly]]
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-1] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 16:38:30.22: pagecode.authorization.Roles : DEBUG : mukul:Persisted element [authToken] value [mukul]
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-1] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 16:38:30.22: pagecode.authorization.Roles : DEBUG : mukul:Persisted element [roleID] value [FullRep]
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-1] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 16:38:30.23: pagecode.authorization.Roles : DEBUG : mukul:Persisted element [prevSelectionspagecode.authorization.Roles] value [{rowTable=[ FullRep]}]
END PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
```

and nothing happens, no error on console no message. the browser window shows that its loading but nothing loads.

This app works good on WAS.

Any help would be appreciated, what could be possible causes of this behavior?

Not sure what other information could be required, please ask if you need anything.

Update #1

tried adding `immediate = "true"`, as per maple_shaft.

following is the stack trace

```
START PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
END PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
START PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 18:41:27.410: ServiceDelegator : DEBUG : :Current Process Stack [[openSession.SelectRole]]
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 18:41:27.411: ServiceDelegator : DEBUG : :Executing Invoke activity [SelectRole]
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 18:41:27.411: ServiceDelegator : DEBUG : :invoking service action class [SET_ROLE]
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 18:41:27.415: BaseServiceAction : DEBUG : :SetRole - Session Key used B9DB051D-8BF4-472D-4000-94BFA0965A49/mukul
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 18:41:27.415: java.lang.Class : DEBUG : :Executing findUserSession().
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 18:41:27.415: java.lang.Class : DEBUG : mukul:Executing persistActiveRoles(UserSession inputUserSession).
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 18:41:27.418: ServiceDelegator : DEBUG : mukul:Current Process Stack [[openSession.SelectRoleSuccess]]
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 18:41:27.418: ServiceDelegator : DEBUG : mukul:Executing Invoke activity [SelectRoleSuccess]
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 18:41:27.418: ServiceDelegator : DEBUG : mukul:invoking embedded process [coordinatorDesktop]
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 18:41:27.418: ServiceDelegator : DEBUG : mukul:Current Process Stack [[openSession.SelectRoleSuccess, coordinatorDesktop.CoordinatorDesktop]]
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logXML:260)  - 2013/02/15 18:41:27.418: ServiceDelegator : XML : mukul:process event final result [<process-step-result><outcome>coordinatorDesktop</outcome><result-params><has-errors><![CDATA[false]]></has-errors><error></error><PROCESS_STACK><![CDATA[openSession.SelectRoleSuccess$$coordinatorDesktop.CoordinatorDesktop$$]]></PROCESS_STACK><PersistElements><roleID><![CDATA[FullRep]]></roleID></PersistElements><Session><![CDATA[USK:B9DB051D8BF4472D400094BFA0965A49/
]]></Session><SelectRoleActionResult><![CDATA[success]]></SelectRoleActionResult><successInd><![CDATA[success]]></successInd><outcome><![CDATA[success]]></outcome></result-params></process-step-result>]
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 18:41:27.418: XMLUtils : DEBUG : mukul:node = error  NOT in XML <process-step-result><outcome>coordinatorDesktop</outcome><result-params><has-errors><![CDATA[false]]></has-errors><error></error><PROCESS_STACK><![CDATA[openSession.SelectRoleSuccess$$coordinatorDesktop.CoordinatorDesktop$$]]></PROCESS_STACK><PersistElements><roleID><![CDATA[FullRep]]></roleID></PersistElements><Session><![CDATA[USK:B9DB051D8BF4472D400094BFA0965A49/
]]></Session><SelectRoleActionResult><![CDATA[success]]></SelectRoleActionResult><successInd><![CDATA[success]]></successInd><outcome><![CDATA[success]]></outcome></result-params></process-step-result>
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 18:41:27.420: pagecode.authorization.Roles : DEBUG : mukul:Persisted element [systems] value [[CLIENT-DB, XMLG, CyberLifeWS, Hibernate, CyberLifeWS_VSAM, AWDnative]]
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 18:41:27.420: pagecode.authorization.Roles : DEBUG : mukul:Persisted element [User] value [mukul]
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 18:41:27.420: pagecode.authorization.Roles : DEBUG : mukul:Persisted element [ServletURL] value [http://localhost:8080/csa/servlet/Initializer]
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 18:41:27.420: pagecode.authorization.Roles : DEBUG : mukul:Persisted element [currSelectionspagecode.authorization.AdminLogon] value [{}]
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 18:41:27.421: pagecode.authorization.Roles : DEBUG : mukul:Persisted element [currSelectionspagecode.authorization.Roles] value [{rowTable= FullRep}]
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 18:41:27.421: pagecode.authorization.Roles : DEBUG : mukul:Persisted element [PROCESS_STACK] value [openSession.SelectRoleSuccess$$coordinatorDesktop.CoordinatorDesktop$$]
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 18:41:27.421: pagecode.authorization.Roles : DEBUG : mukul:Persisted element [Session] value [USK%3AB9DB051D8BF4472D400094BFA0965A49%2F%0C%14%0A%14%0B]
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 18:41:27.421: pagecode.authorization.Roles : DEBUG : mukul:Persisted element [roles] value [[Manager, FullRep, PolAdminRep, loaderRunner, Agent, CustomerService.Level1Analyst, PolOwnerService.Level1Analyst, Approver, AgentFull, OfflineUser, PolOwnerService.ReadOnly]]
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 18:41:27.421: pagecode.authorization.Roles : DEBUG : mukul:Persisted element [prevSelectionspagecode.authorization.AdminLogon] value [{}]
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 18:41:27.421: pagecode.authorization.Roles : DEBUG : mukul:Persisted element [authToken] value [mukul]
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 18:41:27.421: pagecode.authorization.Roles : DEBUG : mukul:Persisted element [prevSelectionspagecode.authorization.Roles] value [{rowTable=[ FullRep]}]
  DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logDebug:145)  - 2013/02/15 18:41:27.421: pagecode.authorization.Roles : DEBUG : mukul:Persisted element [roleID] value [FullRep]
END PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
```

Update #2 : Debug step as suggested by @BalusC

I put a breakpoint on line 594 of `FacesServlet#service()` , control does stop here. 
On stepping into it, the control goes to `LifecycleImpl#render()` line 128. there are thee `if` branches, none of them is evaluated to be true and control returns to `FacesServlet#service()`, `finally` block line 612 and then calls `requestEnd()`.

Update #3 :

As suspected `FacesContext#responseComplete()` has been called during `Invoke_Application` phase.
This is called from `ExternalContextImpl#redirect()` line number #578 . While in the `redirect()` the `else` clause, i.e.  `((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect(requestURI);` is executed

Comment: What JSF impl/version?

Comment: Strange... perhaps an invoked event is forwarding the request to another servlet and it is just waiting.  There could be some stuck process that is dependent on a WAS module to complete.  What happens if you try setting the `immediate` attribute to true on the component invoking the action?

Comment: I might download the source files for the JSF version you are using and start walking through the code starting at the end phase listener event.  That might give you clues.

Comment: @maple_shaft : thanks for your response. i did download the the source code for the distribution.. did walk through.. But honestly I dint get much what happened during that walk.. :D

Comment: @BalusC : its `JSF2.0.2 FCS`

Comment: Wow, that's pretty ancient. As first step, I'd try the latest version.

Comment: @BalusC : yes ancient is pretty decent word. the product I am working on is a _Pre-Historic Beast_ haha :) , I would try the latest version and the `immediate=true` as mapleshaft suggests and get back

Comment: @maple_shaft : please refer to update #1

Comment: @BalusC : I updated app to use JSF 2.1.7 but the behavior is still the same.

Comment: @BalusC : this is what the Jar says `jsf-api-2.1.7.jar` , `jsf-impl-2.1.7.jar`

Comment: OK, just to be sure as it's currently already 2.1.19. Given 2.1.7, put a debug breakpoint on line 594 of `FacesServlet#service()`. Does it get hit? If so, step and look when it stops. If not, put a breakpoint on line 593 and check by exception watch if there isn't an exception which is later silently swallowed.

Comment: @BalusC : I did debug as per your instruction. Please refer to Update #2 in question.

Comment: So .. Some code has called `FacesContext#responseComplete()` during invoke application phase. Put a breakpoint on exactly that method to see who did that.

Comment: @BalusC : Thanks,  Please refer to update 3

Comment: So .. Your concrete problem is thus that a redirect is invoked, but this is not visible to the enduser? Or .. ? I assume that the redirect is normal/desired behavior. It will indeed invoke `responseComplete()`, but that shouldn't cause any problems as the enduser should be redirected to the new URL. Does that step happen or not? Your problem description suggests that the redirect does not happen.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24761/discussion-between-mukul-goel-and-balusc)

Comment: @BalusC : yes a redirect is invoked and is desired behavior. No redirect to new URL happens.

Comment: Okay, the redirect does thus not take place at all. It'd have been helpful if you mentioned the use case from the beginning on... Are you sending an ajax or normal request?

Comment: @BalusC : By that I mean that Nothing is happening, So we see that a redirect is being invoked. But that is not happening. The browser is not redirecting anywhere, rather it continues to be in a state that it is processing the request. But nothing is happening. So basically that was what I was trying to convey with that statement

Comment: @BalusC : Its a normal request. Yes now I see how much time we kind of wasted around it.. :/

Comment: @BalusC : Thank you for your assistance on this. I found out the problem and it had nothing to do with JSF, but some security constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now the problem was not related to JSF but security-constraints configured in `web.xml`.

A constraint was not allowing access to any pages, thus the browser was getting stuck.

But thanks a lot **Bauke Scholtz** for your assistance